# Not getting any reply of QNetworkAccessManager post method

Tags: php, qt4, qtnetwork

I send few binary data with QNetworkAccessManager to a php Url. After receiving the data , php page further sends some data back as forced download after processing. I can see successful post to server , but after that I get no proper response in QNetworkReply , I don't see any signal emitted of it.

```
//mUploadData is QByteArray

mUploadData.append(QString("--" + mBoundary + "\r\n").toAscii());
mUploadData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"UserData\";    

filename=\"UserData.trprof\"\r\n";
mUploadData += "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";    
mUploadData += encryptedPostData;
mUploadData += "\r\n";
mUploadData += QString("--" + mBoundary + "\r\n").toAscii();
mUploadData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"\r\n\r\n";
mUploadData += "Uploader\r\n";
mUploadData += QString("--" + mBoundary + "--\r\n").toAscii();

QUrl serviceUrl = QUrl( "http://localhost/user_data/listen_post.php" );

QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);

request.setRawHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------193971182219750");

// post data to the server.
mNetworkReply = mNetworkAccessManager.post( request , mUploadData );

mDownloadedBytes.clear();


connect( mNetworkReply , SIGNAL( finished() ) , this , SLOT( httpFinished() ) );
connect( mNetworkReply , SIGNAL( readyRead() ) ,  this , SLOT( httpReadyRead() ) );
connect( mNetworkReply , SIGNAL( error( QNetworkReply::NetworkError ) ) ,  this , SLOT( printError(  QNetworkReply::NetworkError ) ) );
```

Here is php code:

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$post_info = file_get_contents($_FILES['UserData']['tmp_name']);

file_put_contents( $file , $decrypted );

$filename = 'test2.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    file_put_contents( $file , filesize($filename) , FILE_APPEND );
    readfile($filename);

    exit;
}

?>
```

Note that , I have tested the php download code with QNetworkAccessManager get method as well as opening the page simply in browser , in both cases I get proper download , but only in case of Qt post I just don't get anything. No signal is emitted , so I can not even tell if an error has occurred , I am simply clueless , what's going on.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Regards
Avanindra Singh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you aren't getting an error back. There's a wrapper for multi-part data, which could help if the issue is with formatting. https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhttpmultipart.html

Have you checked the PHP logs or used Wireshark/tcpdump to see if the request looks correctly formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks nickrak , for the quick response. I got the problem resolved. It seems like I was facing the problem of no signals due to the scope of the object , from which I was posting the data to server. Once I made it non-local , I started receiving signals correctly.